# How to Launch a Mac OS App From Safari Extension?

Tags: swift, macos, safari

Does anyone know what the replacement for the following legacy extension code block to launch a MacOS app is in the new Safari Extensions?

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = "{app_url_scheme}://"
```

We are currently working on transitioning from a legacy extension to support the newer Safari Extensions framework. In the legacy extension we used the following piece code in the global.html file to launch our Mac OS app:

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = "{app_url_scheme}://......."
```

It seems that the comparable code in the new Safari Extension framework would be the following:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "{app_url_scheme}://") else {
    return
}

SFSafariApplication.getActiveWindow {(activeWindow: SFSafariWindow?)in
    activeWindow?.openTab(with: url, makeActiveIfPossible: false, 
    completionHandler: { (activeTab: SFSafariTab?) in
        print("openTab completed")
    })
}
```

However, while the tab will open just fine if it's something like "https://www.cnn.com", it won't do anything if it's just "{app_url_scheme}://". Furthermore, I can type in "{app_url_scheme}://" to the Safari browser and it launches the app just fine, so I know it's not a registration problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this in the future, it seems the code to launch a MacOS app would be the following:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "{app_url_scheme}") else {
   return
}

NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
```